# Python NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined while renaming filenames

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python programming.

And I'm trying to rename filenames inside a folder, so that new filenames will not have any number. E.g. if filename is 123abc.txt then new filename will be abc.txt. The code I've used is below but it is giving error

**NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined**.

Can someone please help, what mistake I've made?

```
import os
def rename_files():
    #Step-1 get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")
    print(file_list)
saved_path = os.getcwd()
print("Current working directory is " + saved_path)
        #Current working directory is C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")
    #Step-2 for each filename, rename filename
for file_name in file_list:
    print("Old Name - "+file_name)
    print("New Name - "+file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

I'm using PyCharm version 2019.3

Comment: you never called `file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")` before you used it. move `rename_files()` in front of the for loop or remove the function and put its content to the regular body of the script

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing file_list before calling rename_files() so, it throws the error. Try to call the method before accessing the file_list.

```
rename_files()
for file_name in file_list:
    print("Old Name - "+file_name)
    print("New Name - "+file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
```

Or you can put this inside of the main body

```
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")
```

Answer (score 0):

file_list was called at end by function rename_files(), but before that only your for loop was trying to access variable file_list. Below is update code.

```
import os

#Step-1 get file names from a folder
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")
print(file_list)

saved_path = os.getcwd()
print("Current working directory is " + saved_path)
        #Current working directory is C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\proj1")
    #Step-2 for each filename, rename filename
for file_name in file_list:
    print("Old Name - "+file_name)
    print("New Name - "+file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
os.chdir(saved_path)
```

Comment: I tried but output is not as expected. @MehaParekh, if possible can you send actual code. user341143 - your code did not meet end result as expected i.e. filenames did not change. I can't place my revise code in the comment because of the character limit.